# Google cardboard in Xamarin is not working

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, xamarin.android, google-cardboard

I developed an app in unity which uses Google cardboard sdk. Our requirement is need to open the unity app inside Xamarin android app. I checked in all forums but i didnt get any proper answer for the same. I got answer like both xamarin and unity runs in Mono framework so it will not integrate in Xamarin. So what i did is we convert unity app in to Android app. After that we import the unity app into android studio and convert that Android app into library project and tired to use the AAR file in xamarin. And i got succeed in that solution. Now the problem is in Xamarin the App is open in normal 2D mode not in Google cardboard mode. I have tired all solution but not able to find a proper solution. Please help me in this problem.

Comment: Have you got some errors? If you have, please show the errors.

Comment: No I didnt get any error. But the app is not opened in Cardboard mode.